# Alternatives for grafana as visualization tool

Tags: jmeter, grafana

Would like to know if you have any idea on the tools similar like grafana , particularly which does not use any databases for saving the datas.

Kindly help us something like light weight tools if possible , which can show graphs just through the jmeter jtl file if posssible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get graphs out of the existing .jtl file the options are in:

1. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of the .jtl results file
2. Opening the .jtl results file with the [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice (applies to [Custom Graphs](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Graphs) as well)
3. Use [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
4. Use [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/)
5. Use online results analysis solution like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

---

If you want realtime results but don't want to invest into infrastructure you can consider running your JMeter test using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool which produces text-based tables and charts during execution:

[image]

or you can configure Taurus to open a browser and show the interactive fancy charts

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Dmitri.. Also eager to know if there are server monitoring tools (using less infra) available as well.